# function for getting window width and height with haskell gloss

Tags: haskell, height, width, screen, gloss

Is there a function, similar to JS `screen.width` and `screen.height` in Haskell with the gloss graphic library, which returns the screen width and height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think gloss itself exports this capability, but you can use these calls from the GLFW package to determine the screen resolution:

```
import Graphics.UI.GLFW

main = do
  initialize
  desktopMode >>= print
  putStrLn "all video modes:"
  videoModes >>= mapM_ print
```

Note that `gloss` may be compiled to use either GLUT or GLFW. If gloss uses GLFW as its interface to Open GL it will call GLFW's `initialize` function when you create a window, and it's possible there is an issue with calling `initialize` twice in the same process but I kinda doubt it.

You can then use these dimensions to set the drawable area when creating a gloss window with the [`FullScreen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.10.2.3/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Display.html#t:Display) constructor.

Answer (score 8):

There is the function is in `Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Environment` called `getScreenSize` it return a `IO (Int,Int)` the first value is width, the second is height.